# Get Topojson from postgresql django

Tags: python, django, geodjango, topojson

I already finish input and run all the geodjango code, it worked. But time after time my data got bigger and result in big size of geojson.
I used this code to read database from postgresql (postgis) as geojson and view it in leaflet :

```
def testcrud_datasets(request):
    testcrud = serialize('geojson', Testcrud.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(testcrud, content_type='json')
```

some solution I read suggest that I should use topojson, how to get topojson format from my postgresql database since serialize does not support topojson type?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can convert to Topojson on the client side by using this library.

https://github.com/topojson/topojson

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
<script>

var topology = topojson.topology({foo: geojson});

</script>
```